# How do you automate the creation of titles from section titles in beamer?

Tags: beamer, titles, counters

I want to automate the creation of titles in beamer such that an environment `Frame` sets the title to this pattern

```
<current-section> (<frame-number>)
```

where `<current-section>` is the title of the current section (including subsection or subsubsection) and `<frame-number>` is the number of the frame *within the current section* (not the total number of frames).

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

% includes

\usepackage{ifthen}

% commands

\newcommand{\CurrentSectionTitle}{%
\ifthenelse{%
    \equal{\insertsubsubsectionhead}{}%
}%
{%
    (...)
}%
{\insertsubsubsectionhead}%
}

\newenvironment{Frame}%
{%
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{\CurrentSectionTitle (\insertframenumber)}
}%
{%
    \end{frame}
}%

\title{Test}
\author{}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}

\frame{
\frametitle{Table Of Contents}
\tableofcontents
}

\section{A}

\subsection{A.1}

\begin{Frame}
\begin{itemize}
    \item a
    \item b
\end{itemize}   
\end{Frame}

\begin{Frame}
\begin{itemize}
    \item c
    \item d
\end{itemize}   
\end{Frame}

\end{document}
```

I was running into trouble getting the current section title using `\ifthenelse` and don't know how to get the number of the current frame witin the current section.

Any ideas, pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is to redefine the `section` and `subsection` commands such that the current title is stored to a global definition (well, bad code so far ;-))

Afterwards, it is checked, whether the `subsection` number is greater then zero,
if so, the `subsection` title is included, otherwise the `section` title.

This could be further worked out, especially the toc entries are wrong so far.

It would also be finer code, to redefine the `frame` environment instead of using  `Frame`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

% includes

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{etoolbox}


\let\LaTeXStandardSection\section
\let\LaTeXStandardSubsection\subsection

\def\CurrentSectionTitle{}%    Two dummy defs
\def\CurrentSubsectionTitle{}%

\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{subsection}{section}
\@addtoreset{framenumber}{section}

\newrobustcmd{\section@noopt}[1]{%
\gdef\CurrentSectionTitle{#1}%
\LaTeXStandardSection{#1}%
}%

\newrobustcmd{\section@opt}[2][]{%
\gdef\CurrentSectionTitle{#2}%
\LaTeXStandardSection[#1]{#2}%
}%



\renewcommand{\section}{%
\@ifnextchar[{\section@opt}{\section@noopt}%
}%


\newrobustcmd{\subsection@noopt}[1]{%
\gdef\CurrentSubsectionTitle{#1}%
\LaTeXStandardSubsection{#1}%
}%


\newrobustcmd{\subsection@opt}[2][]{%
\gdef\CurrentSubsectionTitle{#2}%
\LaTeXStandardSubsection[#1]{#2}%
}%

\renewcommand{\subsection}{%
\@ifnextchar[{\subsection@opt}{\subsection@noopt}%
}%


\makeatother

\newrobustcmd{\CheckWhichTitleToUse}{%
\ifnumgreater{\number\value{subsection}}{0}{\CurrentSubsectionTitle}{\CurrentSectionTitle}%
}%



% commands


\renewcommand{\theframenumber}{-- Frame \arabic{framenumber}}

\newenvironment{Frame}{%
\begin{frame}{\CheckWhichTitleToUse~\theframenumber}%
}{%
\end{frame}%  End code of environment
}% End of newenvironment

\title{Test}
\author{}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}

\frame{%
\frametitle{Table Of Contents}
\tableofcontents
}

\section{A}

% No subsection

\begin{Frame}
\begin{itemize}
    \item a
    \item b
\end{itemize}   
\end{Frame}


\subsection{A.1}

\begin{Frame}
\begin{itemize}
    \item a
    \item b
\end{itemize}   
\end{Frame}

\begin{Frame}
\begin{itemize}
    \item c
    \item d
\end{itemize}   
\end{Frame}

\section{Another Section}



\begin{Frame}
\begin{itemize}
    \item<1-2> e
    \item<2-2> f
\end{itemize}   
\end{Frame}

\begin{Frame}
\blindtext
\end{Frame}


\end{document}
```

---

[image: Frame with section title]
[image: Frame with subsection title]

Comment: @FK82: Ok, please change the `\theframenumber` command at will, I just introduced the style in order to make it more outstanding for demonstration, but not for production

Comment: I will have to go through this step by step first ;) I'm pretty new to how TeX/LaTeX works *under the hood*.

Comment: I readily explain it to you in chat, if you prefer that?

Comment: I'll get back to you on that. Thanks for the offer!

Comment: @FK82: You're welcome... I love to convince others of the *dark side* (`LaTeX`) ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Your code produces an error: `! Undefined control sequence.
l.79 \BeamerStandardFrame
                         {`. Besides, will your `Frame` environment still allow the use of an optional argument for eventual labels, and options such as `fragile`, for example?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Well, the code runs as far used in the example I gave, I did not test further. Optional arguments are not incorporated, I stated in my description that there is still work to be done

Comment: @GonzolaMedina: I see, I posted a correct version, but later on removed a line, I will correct immediately. I appreciate your remark.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks for the fix. And yes, I overlooked that you mentioned that the use of `Frame` has its drawbacks.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: I will come back on the code when I have more time, for the moment, I regard it as a quick hack ;-)